# How to print in webview to bluetooth printer?

Tags: android, printing, webview, bluetooth

I made a web page using spring, and I have to print some page with PDA.

So I tried to using webView in android studio, and I can the web page in PDA.

But I cant find how to print in web view to bluetooth printer, and I've tried to paring between PDA and bluetooth printer. (the window.print fuction is not working in webView)

I just need to print button, but its so hard for me. And I tried to using printooth API but its not working.

Comment: can you post your webview code ?